# How can I find the average word length from the String?

Tags: java

How can I find the average word length from the String text argument? I have void someMethod(String text){}. The word consists of letters and numbers. It is necessary to take into account gaps and punctuation marks

```
public static List<String> someMethod(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split("\\p{P}?[ \\t\\n\\r]+"); // split by whitespace

    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    for (String word : words) {
        double wordLength = word.length();
        sum += wordLength;
        count++;
    }

    final double average = sum / count;

    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length()>= average).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Math.abs(s.length() - "intelligent".length())));

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This seems a lot like homework @cori - we're happy to help with specific code problems but not doing it all for you! I'd recommend looking into the String API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it. Also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: Beyond that: the **first** thing is that **you** get clear on your requirements. We can't tell you *what* your problem is - we *could* only **help** with solving ... after *you* made the first steps yourself.

Comment: You added some code but still didn't describe problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Split string to words using split() method (it is overloaded, I think I would choose one with regexp as parameter) and then iterate over the array(which split () will return) and call length () for each element.

P.S. Before asking, please firstly do these things:
**Try**, **Search**, **Read documentation**

Comment: I edit my question. What are you think? How implement it on java8?

Comment: @cori why the java8 should be related with that? your code is right (at least until the average initialization)